# How to upload and display images in react js by storing them into a database

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, reactjs

I am have trouble uploading and display images. I can not find anyone who does it, can anyone help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot directly upload files to sql database rather we choose different ways to upload images and store the path of that image to sql, below I am going to mention the ways that could be helpful for you for uploading stuff,

1. You can upload the images to a folder inside your client side project and store the path of that image which will be something like, localhost:3000/uploads/image.png, and you can change this path from local to your real server when you will actually upload your project to some server. If you are just doing this in you laptop for practicing you can give path like D://images/image.png, and for getting images you can just use the path and you will receive the image.
2. You can use some cloud storage like aws s3 bucket and directly upload the images there and give the image path in database table same as in the above procedure.

Uploading images to a server is better approach in above point 1 we are upload on local server and second point we are upload aws server but both are servers and in database we are just storing the paths of that uploaded image.

Comment: Is there any sample code that you know of that can help me?

Comment: Here are the articles, using nodejs: [link](https://www.tutsmake.com/upload-image-in-mysql-db-using-node-js-express-multer/)
Using php: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upload-image-into-database-and-display-it-using-php/)

, which language you are using?